# How to transfer lots of user-item pairs into user items matrix?

Tags: r, reshape

#### Sorry, I wrote didn't explain my question correctly before, here's the edited version:

I have lots of data in R data frame looks like this :

```
> data[1:10,]
   user movie score
1     0     0     5
2     0     1     4
3     0     2     5
4     0     3     4
5     0     4     4
6     0     5     5
7     0     6     4
8     0     7     5
9     0     8     5
10    0     9     3
```

Now I want to make it into an big matrix like this :

```
user   m1  m134
1023   5    0    0    0 3 0 0 0 1 0 1 ... 5
2831   0    0    0    0 2 5 0 1 ......... 0
...
```

The first column is user IDs, and the rest fields are movie IDs, if the user scored it, it should present as its score, else 0.

Is there any easy and efficient way to make it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't explicit about the data structure that you want, but this will give you a named list, where the names are the users, and the elements of the list are the vectors of items.

```
# Generate sample data
df<-read.table(textConnection('
user1, item1
user1, item2
user1, item3
user1, item4
user2, item2
user2, item3
user2, item6'))
names(df)<-c('user','item')
# Split 
by(df$item,df$user,function(x)x)

# df$user: user1,
# [1] item1 item2 item3 item4
# Levels: item1 item2 item3 item4 item6
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# df$user: user2,
# [1] item2 item3 item6
# Levels: item1 item2 item3 item4 item6
```

---

Your new question can be done with `acast`.

```
library(reshape2)
acast(data,user~movie)
```

Comment: Sorry, I asked a wrong question, I've already updated it, would you please help again ?

Answer (score 1):

```
# example data
set.seed(1); df <- data.frame(user=sample(1:5, size=10, replace=T),
                              item=sample(1:10, size=10, replace=T))

# convert and print
items <- sapply(unstack(df, form=item ~ user), paste, collapse=",")
as.data.frame(items)
#   items
# 1     8
# 2 3,2,8
# 3     7
# 4  10,4
# 5 4,5,8
```

or

```
paste(names(items), items, sep=", ")
# [1] "1, 8"    
# [2] "2, 3,2,8"
# [3] "3, 7"     
# [4] "4, 10,4" 
# [5] "5, 4,5,8"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a list structure; different length vectors in each component. A simple way to achieve this is to use `split()` on `item`, with groups formed by the variable `user`.

```
split(df$item, df$user)
```

which gives

```
> split(df$item, df$user)
$`user1,`
[1] item1 item2 item3 item4
Levels: item1 item2 item3 item4 item6

$`user2,`
[1] item2 item3 item6
Levels: item1 item2 item3 item4 item6
```